# local changes check different from main

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I got a server with code running.
And I made changes there from ssh and its saves as local changes.
I didn't push them to the git main branch repo, so it stays like that for a while.

And on the main branch repo, it's already updated to the same as the server.
So when I connect via remote explorer extension from vscode, it says there are changes but it is the same as the main branch repo.
is there a way to make vscode check local changes diff from the main branch repo? like a refresh to the Source Control?

Answer (score 0):

If it says they are changes, the [source control view](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol) should show said changes for you, allowing you to add/commit/push.

That is, assuming that the repository is actually clone on the remote server you are SSH'ing to.

Comment: Hey, Yeah repository is cloned to the remote server and on the main branch.
But again it says there are changes cause I changed without pushing them, altho I already pushed those changes from outside the remote server. So its still saying there is changes in the remote server.

Comment: From the remote VSCode SSH session, can you access the Terminal view, go to the root folder of the respository, and do a `git status`? Or a `git pull`?